# Quicksort algorithm with Hoare's Partitioning Scheme returns original unsorted list

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have tried to implement the Quicksort algorithm with Hoare's Partitioning Scheme, but when I run it on a test list `{412, 123, 57, 12, 1, 5}` and then print it out, I get the numbers in original order. Can someone help me spot what I am doing wrong? Below is my implementation.

```cpp
void Quicksort::sort(std::vector<int> &list)
{
   sort(list, 0, list.size() - 1);
}

void Quicksort::sort(std::vector<int> &list, int left, int right)
{
   if (left - right <= 1) return; // no need to partition a single element
   int pivot = left + (right - left) / 2; // <=> (left+right)/2, but avoids overflow
   int endIndex = partition(list, pivot, left, right); 
   sort(list, 0, endIndex - 1);
   sort(list, endIndex + 1, list.size() - 1);
}

int Quicksort::partition(std::vector<int> &list, int pivot, int left, int right)
{
   while (true)
   {
      while (list[left] < list[pivot])
         left++;
      while (list[right] > list[pivot])
         right--;
      if (left != right)
         std::swap(list[left], list[right]);
      else
         return left;
   }
}
```

To call the Quicksort algorithm on the list `{412, 123, 57, 12, 1, 5}` I use the following code:

```cpp
std::vector<int> numbers = {412, 123, 57, 12, 1, 5};
Quicksort::sort(numbers);
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
   std::cout << numbers[i] << "\n";
```

The console output is

```
412
123
57
12
1
5
```

**Edit**

After having fixed the bug `if (left - right <= 1)` which should be `if (right - left <= 1)`, the program encounters the error `Segmentation fault: 11`. This leads me to believe that I am trying to access something that is out-of-bounds.

Comment: Please make it a [mcve]. It seems like you just have to add a couple of lines to do so, small effort for you, but lots of missing pieces for us

Comment: are you sure that `while (list[left] < list[pivot]) left++;` is not going out of bounds?

Comment: @user463035818 I have now added information on how I call my Quicksort implementation and the exact output that I get to make the question Minimal, Complete and Verifiable.

Comment: I do not think that ``while (list[left] < list[pivot]) left++;`` is going out of bounds. If it would, I should get an error shouldn't I?

Comment: `if (left - right <= 1)` Isn't `right` greater than `left`?

Comment: "If it would, I should get an error shouldn't I?" no, in that case your code has undefined behaviour and anything can happen. You cannot count on getting an error

Comment: @Bob__ Yes, you are correct. It should be ``if (right - left <= 1)``. Now that I have fixed this error I am getting the error ``Segmentation fault: 11``, so it indeed seems like something is out-of-bounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The partition part of the algorithm isn't implemented in the correct way. In particular, `left` may become greater than `right` and this

```
if (left != right)
     std::swap(list[left], list[right]);
//             ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Could access the vector out of bounds.

Look at the following snippet:

```
int partition(std::vector<int> &list, int left, int right)
{
   // I'm calculating the pivot here, instead of passing it to the function
   int pivot = list[left + (right - left) / 2];
   while (true)
   {
      while (list[left] < pivot)
         left++;
      while (list[right] > pivot)
         right--;

      // Stop when the pivot is reached 
      if (left >= right)
         return right;

      // Otherwise move the elements to the correct side 
      std::swap(list[left], list[right]);
   }
}

void sort(std::vector<int> &list, int left, int right)
{
    // Execute only if there are enough elements
   if (left < right) 
   {
       int pivot = partition(list, left, right);

       // As NiVer noticed, you have to limit the range to [left, right]
       sort(list, left, pivot - 1); 
       sort(list, pivot + 1, right);
   }
}
```

Testable [HERE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/06iEGiRQceJpKc6z).

Consider also implementing those functions in a more general way, using iterators.

Comment: @Dulvin The partition function does not return when left<right.

Comment: @Dulvin Which function are you considering?

Comment: @Bob__ The partition function.

Comment: @TedLyngmo what will be the value of pivot when it does not return any value?

Comment: @Dulvin It will always return a value. It will return `right` when `left>=right`.

Comment: @Dulvin `left` < `right` is a precondition of that function. Inside it, those indices are updated, but it always return `right`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem (or at least one problem) of the code are the lines:

```
sort(list, 0, endIndex - 1);
sort(list, endIndex + 1, list.size() - 1);
```

This considers always the whole list, and not only the *remaining unsorted* part. You should be using the restricting indexes `left` and `right`:

```
sort(list, left, endIndex - 1);
sort(list, endIndex + 1, right);
```

Comment: But does not ``endIndex - 1`` and ``endIndex + 1`` respectively surve as restricting indices? Because as I see it the left subarray will always start from ``0`` while the right subarray will always end at ``list.size() - 1``, but I guess this is only true for the first call to the partition and not for successive recursive calls.